# Jersey Client POST results in - header full: java.lang.RuntimeException: Header>6144

Tags: json, rest, post, jersey, jetty

Got Jetty 8.1 with Jersey 2.4 as the REST servlet:

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

The GET responses work just fine, but when I try a POST, this strange error is seen from Jetty:

> WARN  o.e.j.server.AbstractHttpConnection - header full: 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Header>6144

The client sees only an HTTP 500 response with no details:

> INFO: 1 * LoggingFilter - Request received on thread main
>   1 > PUT
>   `http://localhost:8080/rest/doPOST`
>   1 > Accept: application/json
>   1 >
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   {"name":"Kris
>   Kringle","trkNbr":"585802240942","rptDt":null,"reqType":"detail"}
>
> Nov 19, 2013 12:59:49 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
>   INFO: 2 * LoggingFilter - Response received on thread main
>   2 < 500
>   2 <
>   Content-Length: 0
>   2 < Server: Jetty(8.1.13.v20130916)
>
> Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException:
>   HTTP 500 Server Error
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:929)

The request is made like this {after the target}:

```
TestPOJO responseMsg = target.path("/rest/doPOST")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .put(Entity.json(reqPOJO), TestPOJO.class);
```

No details in Jetty's log and it doesn't seem it ever makes it to the Jersey servlet.

Comment: The error 500 must be coming from somewhere.  to turn on verbose debugging in Jetty, start jetty with JVM property `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG"` (assuming you are still using Jetty's Standard Logging)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt yeah, using logback at TRACE level and nothing.  That's my problem. No idea what causes it exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error about `header full: java.lang.RuntimeException: Header>6144` means that your response header was over 6144 bytes in size.  The header capacity was at 6144 bytes and your generated header exceeded it.

Why 6144? well, that's calculated based on your [`Buffers`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/io/Buffers.html) implementation.

What `Buffers` implementation are you using? That is determined by the [`Connector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector.html) you are using.

You can set your [`AbstractConnector.setResponseHeaderSize(int)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractConnector.html#setResponseHeaderSize%28int%29) to something larger for yourself.

If you are using standalone Jetty, modify your `etc/jetty.xml` to have the following ...

```xml
...
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        ...
        <Set name="responseHeaderSize">10000</Set>
        ...
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
...
```

This is a quick and dirty fix for your situation.

I encourage you to find out **why** you have a response header that size!  That's not normal and could indicate that you have a much wider and fundamental issue.

Capture the entire HTTP transaction request + response, use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the traffic between jersey-client and the server.

*Note: it might not be possible to see this bad response header from the specific call you are making, as Jetty will fail to generate the header (hence the error) and falls back to a default 500 error response.  Once you increase your responseHeaderSize it might start generating properly, at which point you can capture and look at it.*

Comment: So, that's interesting. The TRACE logging filter is applied to the Jersey servlet and it has tons of info about what Jersey did to respond, like this:

`2 < X-Jersey-Tracing-020: INVOKE      [ ---- /  4.99 ms |  ---- %] Response: [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse @68bdcfdb <200/SUCCESSFUL|OK|`...

I'll see if I dialling it down helps.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Too much info in the header from the amped up TRACE-ing I had configured.