# clojure -AbstractHttpConnection:header full when running against jar

Tags: clojure, jetty

I am getting an error when performing a put from the client to this [service](https://github.com/dagda1/web-game-of-life/blob/master/src/clj/game_of_life/core.clj).  I am using the jetty server.

The error I am getting is:

```
oejs.AbstractHttpConnection:header full: java.lang.RuntimeException: Header>6144
```

This error only happens when I am running against the jar with this command:

```
java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/web-game-of-life.jar clojure.main -m game-of-life.core
```

If I run

```
lein ring server
```

Then all is good.

The payload I am sending is large and if I try with a smaller payload then all is good.

How can set the configuration to increase the header size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20084690/14122 might be worth a glance. Nothing Clojure-specific, but, well, the error is thrown by a Jetty library, which isn't Clojure-specific itself.

Answer (score 2):

Are you usign `liberator`? I had a similar problem because I had liberator request tracing enabled, which would include alot of HTTP headers for tracing the request.

Here's the relevant link: http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/doc/debugging.html